# Using Access VBA to replace string in word generates extraneous space at start of paragraph

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word

I have a table in access that holds paragraphs for letters to go to customers. Each letter have a number of paragraphs.

On our server there is the template document.

I use the code below to paste (in 240 character batches because anything larger generates a "too many characters" error message)

It all works fine except that except for the first line of each paragraph, every line is indented by a space.

I have recreated the word template. I have checked paragraphs and alignment in word.  There are no tab stops either.

I am using windows 10, office 2010, access 2010 front end, sql server back end

One paragraph is too large and is split in 2, but when transferred the join point (in the middle of a word) looks fine.

Code is

```
'3. Build letter text
sPara1 = DLookup("CorroParagraphText", "t_CorroParagraph", "([CPCorroTemplateid] = " & iCorroTemplate & ") and ([CorroParagraphNumber] = " & iPara & ")")
iPara = iPara + 1
sPara2 = DLookup("CorroParagraphText", "t_CorroParagraph", "([CPCorroTemplateid] = " & iCorroTemplate & ") and ([CorroParagraphNumber] = " & iPara & ")")
iPara = iPara + 1
sPara3 = DLookup("CorroParagraphText", "t_CorroParagraph", "([CPCorroTemplateid] = " & iCorroTemplate & ") and ([CorroParagraphNumber] = " & iPara & ")")

'3a. replace strings where needed
sPara1 = replace(sPara1, "[Address]", sSendTo)
sPara1 = replace(sPara1, "[Date]", Format(date, "dd/mm/yyyy"))

'20180117 MO - using alot of Dlookups for practice!
sName = Nz(DLookup("PersTitle", "t_Person", "PersonId = " & iMainPOCPersonId), "")
sName = sName & " " & Nz(DLookup("PersSurname", "t_Person", "PersonId = " & iMainPOCPersonId), "")
sPara1 = replace(sPara1, "[Name]", sName & ",")
sPara1 = replace(sPara1, "[FEC ID]", iFECRef)

sLeadName = DLookup("StaffName", "Staff", "[ID] =" & iLeadStaffId)
sLeadName = sLeadName & " " & DLookup("StaffSurname", "Staff", "[ID] =" & iLeadStaffId)

sLeadJobTitle = DLookup("JobTitle", "Staff", "[ID] =" & iLeadStaffId)
sLeadEmail = DLookup("StaffEmail", "Staff", "[ID] =" & iLeadStaffId)

sLeadStaff = sLeadName & vbCrLf & sLeadJobTitle & vbCrLf & sLeadEmail
sPara3 = replace(sPara3, "[LeadStaff]", sLeadStaff)

strCorroAttach = DLookup("CTAAttachment", "t_CorroTemplateAttachment", "[CTACorroTemplateID] = " & iCorroTemplate)

sContent = sPara1 & vbCrLf & sPara2 & vbCrLf & sPara3

'4. PDF and save letter in customer folder with copy of complaint procedure
'this is where the draft leter will be saved.
DirName = "P:\General Enquiries\Customer_Files\ID " & Format(iFECRef, "0000")
DirContracts = DirName & "\Contracts"
DirOther = DirName & "\Other Info"
DirRenewables = DirName & "\Renewables"

'create the directory if it doesn't exist
If Dir(DirName, vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MkDir DirName
    MkDir DirContracts
    MkDir DirOther
    MkDir DirRenewables
End If

'this is the template that is used to create the letter
strWordTemplate = "P:\Office templates\Whole office\General Templates\FEC Letter NFU.dotx"

strWordVersion = DirName & "\ComplaintID" & iComplaintID & "-" & Format(Now, "yyyymmdd") & ".doc"
' open a new instance of word
Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wrdApp.Visible = True

' open the template
Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(strWordTemplate)

wrdDoc.SaveAs FileName:=strWordVersion, FileFormat:=0

wrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Activate
wrdDoc.ActiveWindow.SetFocus
Set wrdSel = wrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection


wrdSel.Find.ClearFormatting
wrdSel.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

'PARA 1
'20180123 MO - needed to find a way to paste in the other paras longer than 255
'which is why this loop is here
sContent = sPara1

iParaLength = Len(sContent)
iReplaceLoopCounter = 1
Do While (iParaLength > 0)

    sContentTemp = Mid(sContent, (iReplaceLoopCounter * 240) - 239, 240)
    sContentTemp = sContentTemp & "[Start Here]"
    With wrdSel.Find
        .Text = "[Start here]"
        .Replacement.Text = sContentTemp
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    'Debug.Print sContentTemp
    wrdSel.Find.Execute replace:=wdReplaceAll
    iParaLength = iParaLength - (iReplaceLoopCounter * 240)
    iReplaceLoopCounter = iReplaceLoopCounter + 1

    If iParaLength < 0 Then Exit Do
Loop

'PARA 2
sContent = vbCrLf & vbCrLf & sPara2

iParaLength = Len(sContent)
iReplaceLoopCounter = 1
Do While (iParaLength > 0)

    sContentTemp = Mid(sContent, (iReplaceLoopCounter * 240) - 239, 240)
    sContentTemp = sContentTemp & "[Start Here]"
    With wrdSel.Find
        .Text = "[Start here]"
        .Replacement.Text = sContentTemp
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    'Debug.Print sContentTemp

    wrdSel.Find.Execute replace:=wdReplaceAll
    iParaLength = iParaLength - (iReplaceLoopCounter * 240)
    iReplaceLoopCounter = iReplaceLoopCounter + 1

    If iParaLength < 0 Then Exit Do
Loop

'PARA 3
sContent = vbCrLf & vbCrLf & sPara3

iParaLength = Len(sContent)
iReplaceLoopCounter = 1
Do While (iParaLength > 0)

    sContentTemp = Mid(sContent, (iReplaceLoopCounter * 240) - 239, 240)
    sContentTemp = sContentTemp & "[Start Here]"
    With wrdSel.Find
        .Text = "[Start here]"
        .Replacement.Text = sContentTemp
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    'Debug.Print sContentTemp

    wrdSel.Find.Execute replace:=wdReplaceAll
    iParaLength = iParaLength - (iReplaceLoopCounter * 240)
    iReplaceLoopCounter = iReplaceLoopCounter + 1

    If iParaLength < 0 Then Exit Do
Loop

'get rid of the last [Start Here]
sContentTemp = ""
With wrdSel.Find
    .Text = "[Start here]"
    .Replacement.Text = sContentTemp
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
wrdSel.Find.Execute replace:=wdReplaceAll


'save temp file to customer folder
strWordTemplateTemp = DirName & "\ComplaintID" & iComplaintID & "-" & Format(Now, "yyyymmdd") & ".pdf"
    ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
        strWordTemplateTemp, ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
         OpenAfterExport:=True, OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:= _
        wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, _
        IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, CreateBookmarks:= _
        wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, BitmapMissingFonts:= _
        True, UseISO19005_1:=False
```

Thanks - I appreciate any help. This is my first post.

Comment: That's quite a bit of code. Can you come up with a [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem?

Comment: Hi, fair comment.  I will have a look at AJD's comments below and then post M, C, and V code if I am still having issues.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion is the VBA command `Trim` (e.g. `ValidPara = Trim(sPara)`). `Trim` will remove the trailing and leading whitespace from  your paragraph. However, it will also convert multiple spaces inside the paragraph to single spaces. This should be acceptable for your case.

Extending on this is the VBA command `LTrim` (e.g. `ValidPara = LTrim(sPara)`). This only removes the leading spaces and is probably the most appropriate for what you want to do.

Another option is a little more complicated. For this example I am assuming there is only one invalid space in front of the paragraph

```
If Left(sPara,1) = " " Then
    ValidPara = Right(sPara, Len(sPara)-1) ' removes first character from string
End If
```

If you have multiple spaces in front of the paragraph, then you can change the `If-End If` statement to a `While-Wend` loop. In addition, the above code can be modified to strip other strange characters if you ever find yourself in that situation.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your help and advice.  Trimming spaces from the front of the paragraph did not solve the problem, but pointed to what the problem was.

I had to replace "vbcrlf" in my access vba code with "Chr(10) & Chr(13) & ", but I also had to replace "Chr(13) & Chr(10) & " with "Chr(10) & Chr(13) & " for each string I pulled from the access table.  The paragraphs in the table had returns and by identifying the characters' ascii code they came out as 13 then 10.  Switching them around eliminated the leading space.

I don't think I properly described the issue and i should have added an example of the output - this would have made what was going on clearer.  And as Mat's Mug pointed out I should have reduced the code I posted.

Comment: Actually, Word requires only Chr(13) and doesn't use Chr(10) natively. So you could remove the Chr(10) entirely...

Comment: Ok.  I have tested this in my code and it worked without the Chr(10), thanks for letting me know Cindy

Comment: On Stackoverflow you're allowed (even encouraged) to edit both your Question and your Answer to optimize them for others who may run into similar problems :-) And you're welcome!